# netflix conductor timeoutSeconds not taking effect for retries

Tags: conductor, netflix-conductor

I am new to Conductor.
If I understand right, when a worker task (attempt0) timeouts and gets retried according to my task definition, the *timeoutSeconds* should apply as well to the attempt1 and attempt2... but it looks to me it's not working this way. What am I missing here? Thanks.

My worker is sleeping for 10 minutes, attempt0 timeouts as expected, but attempt1 stays in IN_PROGRESS for 10 minutes and finally gets completed.

**workflow definition**

```
{
    "name": "timeout_test_task",
    "description": "timeout test task",
    "version": 1,
    "tasks":
    [
        {
            "name": "step_1_task",
            "taskReferenceName": "step_1_task_ref",
            "type": "SIMPLE"
        }
    ],
    "restartable": true,
    "ownerEmail": "abc@example.com",
    "workflowStatusListenerEnabled": true,
    "schemaVersion": 2
}
```

**task definition**

```
    {
        "name": "step_1_task",
        "retryCount": 5,
        "timeoutSeconds": 10,
        "pollTimeoutSeconds": 1200,
        "timeoutPolicy": "RETRY", 
        "retryLogic": "FIXED",
        "retryDelaySeconds": 1,
        "responseTimeoutSeconds": 5,
        "concurrentExecLimit": 100,
        "rateLimitFrequencyInSeconds": 60,
        "ownerEmail": "abc@example.com",
        "rateLimitPerFrequency": 2
    }
```

UI screenshot of attempt0

[image]

UI screenshot of attempt1

[image]

BTW, attempt0 timeouts after 31 seconds instead of 10 seconds, what's causing this delay?